# Splitting a single-line address into its constituent parts? I'm thinking reg-ex, but I'm not sure?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a .csv of about 8000 rows.  In this csv, one of the fields is a one-line mailing address.  I want to split this one-line mailing address into its constituent parts (street address, city, state, zip code).  Here is what my csv more-or-less looks like:

```
Name| Full Address | Street | City | State | PostalCode

Mary| 123 Yor Street Apt 5 Los Angeles California 12345 |Null | Null| Null | Null |
Bob | 567 Other Ave Chicago Illinois 56789              | Null | Null | Null | Null|
Jim | 890 Last Street COlorado Springs Colorado 80919   | Null | Null | Null | Null|
```

So thats what I have.  What I am looking for is this output:

```
Name     Full Address                                    Street                City          State       PostalCode
Mary | 123 Yor Street Apt 5 Los Angeles California 12345 | 123 Yor Street Apt 5| Los Angeles| California| 12345|
Bob  | 567 Other Ave Chicago Illinois 56789              | 567 Other Ave    | Chicago | Illinois | 56789|
Jim  | 890 Last Street COlorado Springs Colorado 80919   | 890 Last Street | Colorado SPrings | Colorado | 80919
```

Note: The most important parts that I'd like to be able to separate are **City** and **State**, so if the variations on street names (like including apartment #s) complicate things, that can be ignored if I can get **City** and **State** successfully extracted.

I don't have a lot of experience working with strings, So I'm kinda starting at square one.  My first thought is that a regex might be able to parse this out, but I'm not sure how I would construct a regex to identify those things.  Because of this, I'm not sure it's the correct approach.

There are no commas or anything like that which would make obvious separators, which is the other complicating part.  Maybe using `word.split()` on the `Full Address` field and then using a `isin()` with a dictionary of states for the state column?

So, anyone who can provide some direction would be most appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

PS - I apologize for the table formatting.

Comment: just as an FYI - your formatting is fine. we can make a dataframe from what you have provided with `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='|')`. As for the answer, sure, this can be done with regex or `isin()`. It would be a good exercise to go through! Find a string of 5 numbers - thats your zip. find states- thats state. else is address. look at the [`zipcode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zipcode) and [`us`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/us) library

Comment: check out the module "usaddress", it might do what you want: https://github.com/datamade/usaddress  trying to roll your own regex to do this is going to be challenging to get 100% accuracy due to how goofy addresses can be (bad data).

Comment: This is the original string with `NULL` between pipes `Mary| 123 Yor Street Apt 5 Los Angeles California 12345 |Null | Null| Null | Null |` ?

Comment: @sniperd I tried to use the usaddress module, and I dunno why, but it wont work.

I tried the following:

    test = '1 Olympic Plaza Colorado Springs Colorado 80909'
    print(usaddress.tag(test)

this returned 'TypeError: excepted string or bytes-like object` which confuses me greatly because it is a string.  I explicitly converted that to a string as well and tried that, and received the same error.

Comment: @S. Kablar, I'm not clear what you're asking.  Yes, what you typed includes the original string, as well as strings from a few other fields contained in the .csv.  Those strings, the `Null`, are not being called in any code.

Comment: @T.Kelly try this: import usaddress

def main():
    address_list = [
    "123 main street",
    "99 elm st, manchester, nh",
    "56 magic dr, town of, bedford, nh",
    "123 Main St. Suite 100 IL, Faketown",
    ]

    for addr in address_list:
        data = usaddress.tag(addr)
        if "PlaceName" in data[0].keys():
            print(data[0]["PlaceName"])
        else:
            print("no city/town")

main()

Comment: @sniperd that test worked.  I'm modifying that function to return instead of print and passing the string from `FullAddress` as the `address_list`, and gonna give that a try.

Comment: @sniperd that seems to be doing the trick!  Thanks for setting me on the right path. I can modify that function to do what I need to do from here on out!

Comment: @T.Kelly cool, these are other things you can ask for aside from PlaceName:      AddressNumber
    StreetName
    StreetNamePostType
    StreetAddress
    PlaceName (city/town/etc.)
    StateNmae
    OccupancyType
    OccupancyIdentifier  if that does the trick for you let me know and I'll write up a nice answer

Comment: happy to help :)  answer written up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel trying to regex your way out of this is going to be hard.  Address data often is just straight up messy or bad.  I've found the module usaddress to be pretty helpful.  It's not 100% but what is with address matching?

https://github.com/datamade/usaddress

Here is an example:

```
import usaddress

def main():
    address_list = [
    "123 main street",
    "99 elm st, manchester, nh",
    "56 magic dr, town of, bedford, nh",
    "123 Main St. Suite 100 IL, Faketown",
    ]

    for addr in address_list:
        data = usaddress.tag(addr)
        if "PlaceName" in data[0].keys():
            print(data[0]["PlaceName"])
        else:
            print("no city/town")

main()
```

Which results in:

```
no city/town
manchester
town of, bedford
no city/town
```

You can also have it bring back different data aside from PlaceName such as:

```
    AddressNumber
    StreetName
    StreetNamePostType
    StreetAddress
    StateNmae
    OccupancyType
    OccupancyIdentifier
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex would probably not help you here. One solution is to extract the zip code and then make an API-call to get the city and state. With that in place you could afterwards deduct what part is street address and not. (https://ziptasticapi.com/ apparently has a really simple API.)

A prototype could like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

df = pd.read_csv('path to file')

# extract zips
df['zip'] = df['Full Address'].apply(lambda x: x[-5:])

# function to get city and state
def get_city_state(zip):
    url = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/{}'.format(zip)
    response = requests.get(url)
    adress_info = json.loads(response.content)
    return adress_info['state'], adress_info['city']

# add state_city as tuple to your df
df['state_city'] = df['zip'].apply(lambda x: get_city_state(x))

# split tuple into city and state
df[['state', 'city']] = df['state_city'].apply(pd.Series)
```

The API-calls will take some time. So actually I think a better solution would be to extract all unique zips and then store the api-responses in a `dict` or something.

Comment: certainly not the most efficient answer. but I'd say its a unique way of looking at it.