# Edit address data column to extract street using usaddress

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, street-address

I have the following sample address data in `df`:

| address_str |
| --- |
| 99 elm st, manchester, nh |
| 56 magic dr, town of, bedford, nh |
| 123 Main St. Suite 100 IL, Faketown |
| 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, DC 20500 |

How do I use `usaddress` to extract the street name from each of these rows, using `apply()`, and edit the `address_str` column such that it becomes:

| address_str |
| --- |
| 99 elm st |
| 56 magic dr |
| 123 Main St. Suite 100 |
| 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW |

I've already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712081/splitting-a-single-line-address-into-its-constituent-parts-im-thinking-reg-ex) regarding the use of `usaddress` on dataframes but I find the hardcoded sample difficult to adapt to my own needs.

Comment: Addresses are extremely difficult to work manually because of the number of variations. You may find some use of the USPS' address normalisation API which would return for you the proper address forms for your given data

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that would extract the street or any other feature from the address. Here is how you can implement it:

```py
def extract_street(address_str):
    parsed = usaddress.tag(address_str)[0]
    if 'StreetName' in parsed:
        return parsed['StreetName']
    else:
        return address_str

df['address_str'] = df['address_str'].apply(extract_street)
```

this will output:

```
    address_str
0           elm
1         magic
2          Main
3  Pennsylvania
```